# Django CMS - link to uploaded image returns 404

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a Django 1.8.4 site with Django CMS 3.1.3. Via the djangocms-picture plugin I want the editors to be able to upload images to the site. If I upload an image on a page using this plugin, the image ends up in the following folder on the server:

`[PATH_TO_APP_ROOT]/media/cms_page_media/8/`

Where ‘8’ is the id of the page. When I browse the page, the link to the image is given as

https://[MY_SITE]/media/cms_page_media/8/my_image.png

But this link is not correct and I get a 404. I am having a hard time figuring out what I am missing but it seems that there is some URL setting that should be changed.

In settings.py I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join([PATH_TO_APP_ROOT], "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Where `[PATH_TO_APP_ROOT]` is the same as given above. I have not changed any of the media-settings [given in the Django CMS docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.1.x/reference/configuration.html?highlight=media%20url#media-settings) so they should all be default. I am confused that the server looks for the image in `/media/cms_page_media/8/my_image.png` as the `cms_page_media`-part of this URL comes from `CMS_PAGE_MEDIA_PATH` which is not a URL setting(?). What setting do I need to look for to correct this?

Note that everything works perfectly for me in DEV (locally) - the problem is only on the production server.

Comment: Is the app root also the web server root? If `DEBUG` is turned off, django will not serve static or media files, instead let the apache/nginx webserver handle them directly. This means you have to point the media root at a folder handled by the web server, and set up the server's configuration to treat the contents of this folder as static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had time to look into this: The problem was that the web server (pythonanywhere) was not configured correctly. In their admin tool, I had to specify the path to media folder. When I did this, it worked, without having to change any Django settings.

more info here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles